# Android - How to access the USIM's file management?

Tags: android, sim-card, lte

Other than exchanging APDU with the USIM card, how can I access the USIM's file management or perform some operations on the USIM (file deletion, update, and deactivation mainly) ?

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: You should provide a code example of what you tried, and the difficulties you encountered.

Comment: I only tried APDU codes. I am trying to find alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All SIM card communications are based on APDU exchanges. The phone therefore can **only** interact with a SIM using APDUs. Depending on which files you are modifying there my be abstraction type libraries/functions that allow you to edit a SIM contact for example, however you must remember that these libraries are still eventually exchanging APDUs with the SIM.

Maybe if you provide more information around why you require an alternative way to manage SIM files a better answer can be provided?